# Command to run only one specific test plugin defined in Maven

Tags: testing, maven-2, command-line

I have a Maven POM file with a plugin that runs on the test phase. What command line arguments do I have to pass mvn in order to execute just that plugin rather than all of the plugins for that phase? I am also trying to execute a specific ant-run plugin, that looks like the following:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jslint4java</groupId>
            <artifactId>jslint4java-ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jslint</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <ant antfile="${basedir}/jslint.xml">
                  <property name="root" location="${basedir}" />
                  <target name="jslint" />
                </ant>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the fully-qualified goal in the form of:

```
mvn groupID:artifactID:version:goal
```

For example:

```
mvn sample.plugin:maven-hello-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:sayhi
```

---

**EDIT:** I'm modifying my answer to cover the update of the initial question and a comment from the OP.

I won't cover all the details but, it the particular case of the antrun plugin, you could just run:

```
mvn antrun:run
```

But now that you've updated the question, I understand that things are a bit more complicated than what I thought initially and I don't think that this will actually work. I mean, invoking `mvn antrun:run` won't fail but it won't pick up the `configuration` of the `execution` bound to the `test` phase.

The only (ugly) solution I can think of would be to add another maven-antrun-plugin configuration in a **specific profile**, something like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.jslint4java</groupId>
        <artifactId>jslint4java-ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <tasks>
        <ant antfile="${basedir}/jslint.xml">
          <property name="root" location="${basedir}" />
          <target name="jslint" />
        </ant>
      </tasks>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And to use this profile when calling `antrun:run`:

```
mvn antrun:run -Pmyprofile-for-antrun
```

Comment: thanks Pascal, any hints on the commands for executing the specific ant run plugin?

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I had a feeling that it might have to involve a profile hack in order to work. Damn. Hopefully soon the JSLint Plugin will get a dedicated Mojo for it. I think one is currently in the works.